# How to display data to textfield from combo selection in laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Display data to textfield based combo selection dynamicaly]

I'd like to display data to textfield based on combo/drop box selection in laravel 5.8. then save the data. is there complete tutorial how to do it from model, view and controller.

In Customer Controller

```php
    public function create()
    {
        $customer= Customer::all();
        return view('Customer.create', compact('Customer'));
    }
```

in view create.blade

```html
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>CUSTOMER</strong>
                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="kde_cust" id="cde_customer" required>
                    <option value=""> -- PICK CUST-- </option>
                    @foreach($cust as $cust)
                        <option value="{{ $cust->cde_cust }}" selected>{{ $cust->nme_customer }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>NAME</strong>
                <input type="text" name="cust_name" id="cust_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $cust->nme_customer }}">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If understood, what you want is to select the customer and then show the address inside the textfield?

Comment: yes it is right. dynamically when the combo select Mr B then textfield show Addr B so on...

Comment: The address is a column on customers table or you have an address table with the customer_id as foreing key?

Comment: addrress is a column on customer table

Answer (score 0):

This should helps:

Create a route to get the user address:

```php
Route::get('user-address/{user_id}','YourController@method')->name('user.address');
```

Your controller method should look like this:

```php
public function yourFunction($cde_customer)
{
    $customer = Customer::where('cde_customer', $cde_customer)->first();
    $address = $customer->address;
    return response()->json([
       'address' => $address,
    ]);
}
```

Add this script to your blade:

```php
$("#cde_customer").on('change', function(){
    var user_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/user-address/' + user_id,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            $("#textfield").html(response.address);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.